# Efficient way of getting all records that are (or aren't) referenced in a belongs_to relationship?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a model A and a model B where B belongs_to A, what is the most efficient method of finding all A's that have at least one B? Similarly, what is the most efficient for finding the opposite (All A's that have no B's).

Comment: Inner join A and B for all values that correspond between the 2. Then Left join A on b, with a where clause of b.SomeColumn IS NULL

Comment: can you share your current thought process? stack overflow isn't for Q/A of homework.

Comment: @lplatz what part of this question looks like homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
# All A's that have no B's
A.eager_load(:B).where('B.id is null') 
# or
A.eager_load(:B).where(B: { id: nil })

# all A's that have at least one B
A.joins(:B).where('B.id is not null')
# or this should already do the trick because inner join will ignore null records in B
A.joins(:B)
```

Remember to change `B` into your table name in plural.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to involve the least amount of querying the database. I was figuring rails would have a rails-y method for this type of query, but I think that is the closest I will get